# doGet(e) for display cell in Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to display the contents of some cells of a spreadsheet. I wont be passing the range of cells through the `doGet()` parameter.
This is my code, but it does not work:

```
function doGet(e) {
 var key = e.parameter.key;
 var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yl2dFder89Ox4u-3wAtybbdOdITsR243BjmrazpU9-M/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var temp= ss.getRange(key).getValues();  
  
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(temp);
}
```

Comment: See [mre] and [ask]. Explain in detail: *but, it not works*

Comment: Welcome. Insert `Logger.log("key = "+key);` after line 2; insert `Logger.log("the range is " + ss.getRange(key).getA1Notation());` after line 4; insert `Logger.log(temp);` after line 5. View the results in the log, and edit your question to include the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Provide a query string like this:

`https://script.google.com/a/.../exec?range=Sheet1!A1:C3`

```
function doGet(e) {
  var rngA1=e.parameter.range;
  Logger.log(rngA1);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadsheetId");
  var content='\n' + ss.getRange(rngA1).getValues().map(function(r){return r.join(',');}).join('\n');
  Logger.log(content);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(content);
}
```

This will output all the cell value in each row with linefeed at the end of each row.

Comment: THank you so much is just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Provide a query string like this:

https://script.google.com/a/.../exec?range=Sheet1!A1:C3

function doGet(e) { var rngA1=e.parameter.range; Logger.log(rngA1); var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadsheetId"); var content='\n' + ss.getRange(rngA1).getValues().map(function(r){return r.join(',');}).join('\n'); Logger.log(content); return ContentService.createTextOutput(content); }

This will output all the cell value in each row with linefeed at the end of each row.

se-share-sheet#willShow s-popover:shown->se-share-sheet#didShow" style="box-sizing: inherit; margin: 0px; padding: 8px; border: 0px; font-style: inherit; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; line-height: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 11px; vertical-align: baseline; color: rgb(159, 166, 173); text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block;">share edit

answeredSep 22 at 16:00

Cooper
13.6k●33 gold badges●99 silver badges●3333 bronze badges

THank you so much is just what I was looking for!– Michele Pupin Sep 23 at 18:52   Delete

add a comment

up vote-1down voteaccept

Response

Good morning, excuse me for making me feel again. But unfortunately the code gives me this error that I don't understand.

The error is : Invalid value (line 4, file "code", "steak trial" project) you see the image.

Thanks Michele!